# Deploy PHP using cURL in GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

I just received a great news that full cURL is supported now.
I followed the instruction to replace "runtime:php" with "runtime:php55" in app.yaml and deployed my php code to Google App Engine using Google App Engine Launcher.

The system responsed error as attached:

```
..deploy response...............
2015-02-27 23:01:52 Running command: "['C:\\python27_x64\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=jihshiun@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'D:\\Documents\\GAE CloudSite\\Hi']"
Usage: appcfg.py [options] update <directory> | [file, ...]

appcfg.py: error: Error parsing D:\Documents\GAE CloudSite\Hi\app.yaml: Unable to assign value 'php55' to attribute 'runtime':
Value 'php55' for runtime does not match expression '^(?:contrib-dart|dart|go|php|python|python27|java|java7|vm|custom)$'
  in "D:\Documents\GAE CloudSite\Hi\app.yaml", line 3, column 10.
2015-02-27 23:02:04 (Process exited with code 2)
.......................
```

I also tried to add a php.ini with extension = "curl.so" in the file, and the deployment failed too with the same response.

Have I missed something?
Please advise.

Comment: If it's a new feature, the sdk probably got updated when they added it. Try updating. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_PHP

Comment: Jeremiah is correct. php55 is a new feature that only works with GAE SDK 1.9.18 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

You have to update the sdk, [download](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads) the file corresponding to your plataform and instal it.